# Change Dropdown option on Button Click in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want to change the dropdown options dynamically on click of button

HTML Code

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
     <li ng-controller="exerciseTypeCtrl">
          <select id="exerciseType" data-role="listview" ng-options="type as type.text for type in types.cast " ng-model="item" ng-change="update()">
          </select>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Using This JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('exerciseTypeCtrl',function($scope,indoors,outdoors)
{
    $scope.types = indoors;
    $scope.update = function() {
    }
});
```

By Default I bind data `indoors` and I want to bind `outdoors` data on ng-click event so drop down updates dynamically
I need Help on this issue

Comment: Unless there is something you are not including in your question, this seems simple enough. What have you tried ?

Comment: i want to change data in dropdown when say. some botton click event
what i have to do in that click event of button to replace data to the new one i have tow datas one in `indoors` that already bind and other is `outdoors` that i want to replace on click event
i am new in angular-js

Comment: @SimonBelanger please check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932585/angular-js-drop-down-values-change-dynamically

Comment: Do the object indoors and outdoors have some properties?

Comment: @Chandermani
my indoor and outdoor objects are like below
var outdoors = {};
 outdoors.cast = [{
  value: "00",
  text: "OutDoor"
 }];
        var indoors = {};
 indoors.cast = [
 {
  value: "11",
  text: "InDoor"
 }];
yes

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.update = function() {
};
```

Replace To:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    $scope.types = outdoors;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vKECj/)

Answer (score 0):

For this you should make `button` under the same `ng-controller` scope in which you defined `select` component and then on `ng-click` event of that `button` you call `function` which you will create in same controller like your `update function` and in that function you will assign new values like `$scope.types = outdoors`in it

I create simple [example](http://addr.pk/a974) for this you should check this out
Thanks